# Writing Javascript using UTF-16 character encoding

Tags: javascript, web-applications, character-encoding, utf-16

Here is what I am trying but am not sure how to get this working or if it is even possible -

1. I have an HTML page `MyHTMLPage.htm` and I want to  `src` a Javascript from this HTML file. This is pretty straightforward. I plan to include a `<script src = "MyJavascript.js"></script>` tag in my HTML file and that should take care of it.
2. However, I want to create my Javascript file using UTF-16 encoding. So, I plan to use the following tag `<script charset="UTF-16" src="MyJavascript.js"></script>` in my HTML file to take care of that
3. Now the problem I am really stuck at is how do I create the Javascript using UTF-16 encoding - E.g. let's say my Javascript code is `alert(1);` I created my Javascript file with the contents as `\u0061\u006c\u0065\u0072\u0074\u0028\u0031\u0029\u003b` but that does not seem to execute as valid Javascript at runtime.

To summarize, here is what I have -

### MyHTMLPage.html

```
...
...
...
<script charset="UTF-16" src="MyJavascript.js"></script>
...
...
...
```

### MyJavascript.js

```
\u0061\u006c\u0065\u0072\u0074\u0028\u0031\u0029\u003b
```

When I open the HTML page in Firefox, I get the error - "`Syntax error - Illegal character`" right at the beginning of the `MyJavascript.js` file. I have also tried adding the BOM character "`\ufeff`" at the beginning of the above Javascript but I still get the same error.

I know I could create my Javascript file as - "`alert(1);`" and then save it using UTF-16 encoding using the text editor and then the browser runs it fine however is there a way I could use "`\u`" notation (or an alternate escape character) and still get the Javascript to execute fine?

Thanks,

Comment: You're not trying to secure your JavaScript code, are you?

Comment: are you just trying to obfuscate your JS??  if so, try [this](http://www.jsobfuscate.com/index.php) or [this](http://www.javascriptobfuscator.com/default.aspx) or if all else fails, there's always [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=obfuscate+javascript)

Answer (score 2):

You are misunderstanding character encoding. Character encoding is a scheme of how characters are represented as bits behind the scenes.

You would not write `\u004a` in your file to "make it utf-16" as that is literally a sequence of 6 characters:

`\`, `u`, `0`, `0`, `4`, `a`

And if you saved the above as utf-16, it would be represented as the following bits:

```
005C0075
00300030
00340061
```

Had you saved it as utf-8 it would be:

```
5C753030
3461
```

Which takes 50% of the space and bandwidth. It takes even less to write that character literally (`"J"`): just a byte
(`4A`) in utf-8.

The `"\u"`-notation is a way to reference any BMP character by just using a small set of ascii characters. If you were
working with a text editor with no unicode support, you could write `"\u2665"`, instead of literally writing `"♥"` and the
browser would show it properly.

If you for some weird reason still want to use utf-16, simply write the code normally, save the file as utf-16 and serve it with the proper charset header.